# Code for filtering Dimensions

Tags: dimension

I'm working in DAX2012 and the form ForecastSales. 
On the tab tabPageFilter I want to add fields for dimensions and check-boxes connected to the dimension - in the same way as filter on item. How do I do that?
When the user has entered values in this filterfields I have to write code to filter. This would normally be done using QueryBuildRange, but I don't know how to use that on dimensions in DAX2012. 
I can find all forecastSales with the selected dimension using DimensionAttributeValueSetStorage class, but I can't use that in a QueryBuildRange.
Any ideas how to solve this?